# Open as Write-mode close as Read-only

Tags: vba, excel, ms-project

I'm writting VBA in MS Project and need to open an Excel file to save some stuff. This Excel file might be in use by someone else. So I'd like to save the file as Read-only and when it is opened via VBA change to Write-mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

```
'Before opening the book I set to vbNormal
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    SetAttr supportDoc_loc & Dir(master_statusGlobal_loc), vbNormal
    Set xlbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(master_statusGlobal_loc)

'After the changes I close the book as vbReadOnly
    xlbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    SetAttr supportDoc_loc & Dir(master_statusGlobal_loc), vbReadOnly
```